# What is wrong with my PDF?

Tags: probability, statistics

The question is suppose that in a certain year, an alien attack will happen at a uniformly random time on July 4th. Let X be a continuous random variable representing the time of the attack in hours after midnight.

For 0 < x < 24, what's the value of the PDF, f(x)?

I started by doing

```
x=0    .1
x=1    .1
x=2    .1
```

all the way to 24 (because there are 24 hours in a day)

I have realized this is most likely incorrect and would like some help starting.

The second question is what's the probability the aliens attack before 6 am?

I thought of it like this

```
12am - 6 am - the time they can attack
6:01am - 11:59 pm - time they cannot attack 

P(cannot attack/can attack) = 6/16 = 37.5% chance
```

Please let me know if I am correct, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- X is continuous, not discrete, so it's not right to assign P(x=0)=.1
  (in any case, it would make more sense to assign 1/24 to this
  probability, if it were discrete). Instead, the pdf must integrate to
  1 from 0 to 24. $\int_0^{24}\frac 1 {24}dx=1$, so the pdf is
  $f_X(X)=\begin{cases}\frac 1 {24}&0\le x\le
     24\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. The probability that an attack
  happens between 12 am and 6 am is 6/24, because it's uniform. In
  math: $\int_0^6 f_X(x)dx=\int_0^6\frac 1 {24}dx=\frac 6 {24}$
- Your calculation is called an **odds ratio** of an attack, 6/18. You
  want the **probability** of an alien attack.

Comment: So I understand that the PDF would be that, makes total sense, but I do not really understand how to solve for f(x), would it simply be a table (like I had) but instead of .1 would it be 1?

Comment: The question says it's continuous uniform, so if you have two boundaries, a and b the pdf is given by $f(X)=1/(b-a)$ if X is between a and b, and 0 otherwise (here is a=0 and b=24). There are two types of uniform distributions continuous and discrete. For continuous X can take any value between a and b but for discrete X can take only the integer values between a and b.

Comment: So then if I wanted to find the expected value of X, would it just be 1x0+1x1+1x2.....+1x24?

Comment: The mean is $\frac 1 2(b-a)=\frac{24}{2}=12$

Comment: @overlord12 Sorry, that's wrong it's $\frac 1 2(a+b)=\frac {24} 2=12$